# Apps pinned to taskbar don't start anymore

Tags: windows-10, taskbar

There doesn't seem to be any problems with windows store apps, but for regular apps (e.g. File Explorer, Firefox), pinning them to the taskbar creates the shortcut (.lnk file) in `%AppData%\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Quick Launch\User Pinned\TaskBar`, but clicking on the taskbar icon gives the message:

> This file does not have an app associated with it for performing this action. Please install an app or, if one is already installed, create an association in the Default Apps Settings page.

Double-clicking the link in the TaskBar folder opens the app without any problems.

Apps that open include calculator, slack, windows terminal, windows store and the fb-messenger app (downloaded from the app store). Apps that do not launch include explorer.exe (opens with windows+e and from the start menu), "C:\Program Files\Firefox Developer Edition\firefox.exe" (opens from the shortcut and from the start menu), Word ("C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\root\Office16\WINWORD.EXE") opens fine from the start menu, all other office apps, PyCharm, WebStorm, Visual Studio 2015, emacs - all of them open through the start menu.

Some apps (e.g. Redis Desktop Manager) will not pin to the taskbar, i.e. clicking the pin-to-taskbar menu item is a no-op.

This is a brand new win10 pro system. This worked until a couple of days ago (I believe there was an update that auto-installed, but I'm not sure..)

Creating a new local (administrator) account and trying to start file explorer (which by default is pinned to the taskbar) displays the same symptoms.

Any ideas..?

Comment: Please list the specific programs that are not starting from the pinned shortcuts. There are no "links" on the Taskbar, these are shortcuts. Do these programs run when you open them via another method?

Comment: @music2myear I was referring to .lnk files. Apps that open include calculator, slack, windows terminal, windows store and the fb-messenger app (downloaded from the app store). Apps that do not launch include explorer.exe (opens with windows+e and from the start menu), "C:\Program Files\Firefox Developer Edition\firefox.exe" (opens from the shortcut and from the start menu), Word ("C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\root\Office16\WINWORD.EXE") opens fine from the start menu, all other office apps, PyCharm, WebStorm, Visual Studio 2015, emacs - all of them open through the start menu.

Comment: fwiw, creating a new local account and trying to start file explorer (which by default is pinned to the taskbar) displays the same symptoms.

Comment: This information needs to be added to the original question. It should not be necessary to read comments to comprehend the issue.

Comment: @music2myear updated.

Comment: Have you rebooted. This happens to me often and a reboot fixes it.